# Why does statistical significance calculator does not ask for population size?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, sample

Still trying to grasp the right way to calculate with statistical significance. I believe to calculate with statistical significance, you must know your total population size first - but why does all of the A/B Test result calculator does not need a Population Size input? Am I missing something here.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "all of the A/B ... calculator."  Evidently, whatever calculators you are using assume there is no population (there's just a process that can yield an arbitrarily large number of observations) or else that the population is huge compared to any sample sample size you might contemplate.

Comment: Population size or sample size?

Answer (score 0):

The population size is almost always irrelevant, unless the sample size is close to the population size.  There is a finite population correction factor:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}
$$

where N is the population size and n is the sample size. Plugging in various values of N and n shows that, usually, this factor is tiny. Therefore, most power analysis programs will ignore it.